# How to create a layout with top-floating controls and autosize?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, user-controls, controls

I'm currently stuck at creating a layout for a WinForms Control:

My usercontrol hosts the following subcontrols:

```
RichTextBox
Label B
  Control B
  Control B
  Control B
Label C
  Control C
  Control C
Label D
  Control D
  Control D
```

The RichTextBox is always visible. It's height should grow as big as it needs to be to display all text without ScrollBars.

Depending on my dataobject, I want to display several additional information if present. For instance, there can be 5 controls B, 0 C and 20 D.
I want the controls to "float" to the top. Each control should be able to grow in height in order to display it's full content.

I've tried numerous combinations of TableLayoutPanels, FlowLayoutPanels, docking and autosize settings, but none of them fulfilled my expectations.

How can I arrange my controls in the order I posted above with the features dock top and autosize?

Comment: It's not very clear what "float to the top" means.  Top of what?  Over the RichTextBox?  Where over the RichTextBox?

Comment: I try to clarify: There should be no wasted vertical space between the controls. The first control should be the RichTextBox, directly beneath Label B (if present), followed by the first Control B, ..., followed by Label C (if present) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create outer TableLayoutPanel with 4 rows and 1 column. Set `SizeType = AutoSize` for rows.
2. Place RichTextBox into first row.
3. Create inner TableLayoutPanel with so many rows, as your controls count, and 2 columns. Set `SizeType = AutoSize` for all rows. Set `AutoSize = true` for inner TableLayoutPanel. Place it to next row.
4. Place Label to first cell. Set `ColumnSpan = 2` for lable.
5. Place controls into second column of other rows.
6. Repeat 3-5 for other inner `B` and `C`